# ViewBag property always returning null in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am trying to test that ViewBag data is being populated from my controller, but in my unit tests my property returns null no matter what I set.

**controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogEvent(LogLevel.Trace, null, $"Landing page requested", null);
        ViewBag.InstrumentationKey = _instrumentationKey;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

**unit test:**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIndexHasApplicationInsightsKey()
    {
        // Arrange            
        var mock = new Mock<ILogging>();
        mock.Setup(logging => logging.LogEvent(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>())).Verifiable();
        HomeController controller = new HomeController(mock.Object);

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreNotEqual(null, result.ViewBag.InstrumentationKey as string);
    }
```

**result:**

> Assert.AreNotEqual failed. Expected any value except:<(null)>. Actual:<(null)>.

I read a few answers that said I should be accessing my property view ViewData["InstrumentationKey"], but that always returns null also.

Any idea what I am doing wrong that wouldn't allow me to test the ViewBag properties value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For demonstrative purposes the following was tested

```
[TestClass]
public class MyViewBagTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIndexHasApplicationInsightsKey() {
        // Arrange            
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreNotEqual(null,result.ViewBag.InstrumentationKey as string);
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        ViewBag.InstrumentationKey = "Hello world";
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

to prove that it does in fact work when tested. Which it does, as it passes when tested.

This would lead me to believe that `_instrumentationKey` in your method under test is in fact **`null`** when the test is exercised.

I suggest you review when that variable is populated, making sure that a value is assigned during the exercising of the method under test.

Comment: I think you are right. After reading your comment, I realized they instrumentationkey is populated from a app setting in my web.config file; that setting doesnt exist in my unit test config.